# Magento 2: How to show shipping amount without refreshing my cart page?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, php-7

I try to bring the amount of the shipment from the backend without javascript. But when the cart page is displayed for the first time, the shipping amount is displayed as follows:

[image]

but when I refresh the page, then the amount of the shipment is shown as it should be:

[image]

This is my backend code, to get the shipping amount:

```
<?php
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$shipping_amount=$cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();?>

  <tr>
<td>Shipping (<?php echo $shipping_amountc; ?>) </td>
<td align="right"><?php echo number_format($shipping_amount,2);?></td>
```

Is there any way to bring the shipping amount without refreshing the page? please who can help me, I appreciate it!